# Formula field does not recognize "System Administrator" profile name

Tags: formula-field

I am using an IF statement to populate a formula field.

The following does not work and always returns false:

```
IF(Profile.Name == "System Administrator", "Yes", "No")
IF(CONTAINS(Profile.Name, "Admin"), "Yes", "No")
```

However, using the Profile ID works:

```
IF(Profile.Id == "00000000", "Yes", "No")
```

Why does the name not work in any case? I would assume matching "System Administrator" or "Admin" would not be this tricky.

Comment: Is `"System.Administrator"` a typo? There shouldn't be a period/full-stop between "System" and "Administrator".

Comment: @DerekF Yes, you're correct, that was a typo.

Answer (score 2):

Global variable is referenced with $ in front.

```
$Profile.Name = 'System Administrator'
```

Answer (score -1):

If you use $Profile.Name = 'System Administrator' it will consider the profile name of the running user. But If you want to compare System Administrator profile of the user record.

Try IF(Profile.Name == " PT1", "Yes", "No")